# Как в тесты сервисов и контроллеров передать OAuth2Authentication

Tags: java, spring

В методы контроллера и сервиса приходит параметр OAuth2Authentication. Как можно его передать(сгенерировать) в тестах в контроллера и сервиса?

Пример метода из сервиса

```
    @Transactional
    public void update(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
      ...
    }
```

Пример метода из контроллера

```
    @PutMapping
    public void update(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        service.update(authentication);
}
```

**UPD:**
В тестах сервисов я использую аннотацию `@WithUserDetails(value = "test@gmail.com")`, чтобы достать из бд существующего пользователя.

Далее с помощью  `ResourceServerTokenServices` через токен достаю `OAuth2Authentication` выглядит это следующим образом:

```
OAuth2Authentication authentication = resourceServerTokenServices.loadAuthentication(token);
```

Из `authentication` мне надо достать `Details`. И возникает проблема, в тестах там сразу лежит `LinkedHashMap`, а если отправлять запрос через Postman, то в `Details` лежит `OAuth2AuthenticationDetails`.

Я через дебаг посмотрел, как формируется `OAuth2Authentication`. Там приходит
`PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken`, где в поле `Details` лежит `OAuth2AuthenticationDetails`.

Тестах это поле даже не формируется. Можно ли как то в тестах создать `OAuth2Authentication` c нужными полями, или создать  `authentication`, где поле  где в поле `Details` лежит `OAuth2AuthenticationDetails`?

Comment: тут посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326028/java-spring-mvc-integration-test-create-oauth2-principal

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Я дополню вопрос